# Android: Theme and style

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme

I try to create a app that allow use to change the theme in the app,
But I can't find out how do define the style and theme if I will have multi Theme.

In CSS I will do by this for example

```
File: Theme1.css
    div.button {
       font-color: red;
    }


File: Theme2.css
    div.button {
       font-color: blue;
    }
```

And then by include one of this select what theme I will use.

I has look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html but this what I can 
find out do not show how do define If use has multi theme.

Can somebody give me a small example for say

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="0dip" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
                android:layout_height="20sp"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

That set color and font-size of the text?
And allow the Activity to select one of the themes.

Comment: Look at this example. I think you should find solution here . http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Comment: Good link, and show how this work :)